# image element will not reach the edges of the container and thus line up with the header and footer image elements

Tags: css

Why doesn't the main image element in the main content, meet the edges of the container. For some reason I just can't figure out why it won't stretch.

Any thoughts?

page link - http://www.carpenter-and-walrus.co.uk/sympathy.html

Element - funeral-wreath-sunflowers-c.gif

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not on the edge of the page - I guess its about 10px out on either side.

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` elements don't stretch unless you explicitly set their width and/or height. Your image is 970 pixels wide and will stay that way unless you manually set it to something else.

Also, your header and main images are larger than their containers can accommodate. The usable width of a container is (usually) `width - padding` so if you have a 1000px wide container with 20px padding on both sides you'll only have 960px available for the contents.

If you need a quick and dirty fix, set `width: 1000px` for the main image (and also adjust it's height to preserve aspect ratio) and give both the header and main image some negative `margin-left` to offset them to where you want them.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kaivosukeltaja for your help - all fixed now!

Comment: @user1845421: Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark the answer as "Accepted" (green check mark on the left) if it solved your problem.